# How can I make the ER diagram of this library?

Tags: database, entity-relationship

I've been asked by my teacher to make the ER diagram of a certain library. Here is a very simple and not complete ER diagram only to illustrate my point: [image]

Searching the library's website I found exactly the attributes I need for the customer, for the copies the book etc. However, the book is not the only thing provided by the library. The library provides music-CDs , journals, DVDs and many more leading to 20 different kinds of items in total.

One very ugly solution would be to create a different entity for all these items and connect each one of them with the copy entity. And this seems unavoidable since each item type has different attributes. A book for example has ISBN and a journal the ISSN. Looking at all the attributes of each item the only thing they all have in common is a title.

Is there a better way to do the ER diagram?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

unfortunately no, he is asking for an academic solution and the way to represent the mini-world in er is 1 entity type per object. this is my vision to ER diagrams in its simplest academic form.
if you continue to sum entity types together, your entire mini world will be one entity type.